# how to change cassandra docker config

Tags: authentication, docker, cassandra, config

I installed cassandra from cassandra hub and its running successfully.

```
root@localhost$ docker ps | grep cassandra
2925664e3391        cassandra:2.1.14        "/docker-entrypoin..."   5 months ago        Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:7000-7001->7000-7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7199->7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9160->9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32779->7000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32778->7001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32777->7199/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32776->9042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32775->9160/tcp
```

I am connected my application with this cassandra. I need to use password authentication to connect to cassandra form my application.

I have to unable password authentication for this, I get the `/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml` file in docker image. I have to follow [Authentication Config](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html) to enable this.

Is there way to override this changes with `docker start` or `docker run` command ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to connect other containers to this instance? Have you followed [the instructions the maintainers posted on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/)?

Comment: Sorry if you not understand my question, but I want to connect my application to cassandra with `password`, right now, its accepting conneciton without username/password. I want to restirct that, means only application which has, username/password only can connect to my docker cassandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not included into the piece generating the cassandra.yml file, so no. You can submit a PR modifying the [relevant piece](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/d83b850cd17bc9198876f8686197c730e29c7448/2.1/docker-entrypoint.sh#L37) of the generation script to allow to specify auth via env variables.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, is there any way to enable password authentication in cassandra ?

Comment: Yes, you modify [the script](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/d83b850cd17bc9198876f8686197c730e29c7448/2.1/docker-entrypoint.sh#L37) to generate [auth properties](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__SecurityProps). Basically it means forking the image and submitting a pull request to the maintainers

Comment: Thnks Ivan, let me try this.

Comment: did anyone get a solution for that issue?